# HTML/ JavaScript onmouseover onclick multiple events

Tags: javascript, html, events

This question undoubtedly has a simple answer however I have not been able to find it.  I want to fire a javascript function on onmouseover but a page change onclick.  Should I try to accomplish both in javascript or can I do the mouseover in javascript and the page change somehow in html.

This fires the javascript function fine.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="previewBox;">Preview</a>
```

However, the following is not working and I can't figure out how to change page on click:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="previewBox;" onclick="newpage.php?p=1&q=3">Preview</a>
```

I can imagine creating a second javascript function to fire the php script where you pass all the parameters up to the javascript and then use it to launch the php script but that seems rather clumsy

Thanks for any simple suggestions.

Comment: if your "onclick" is a simple page change - you should use <a> as it's meant to be used - as a link. Also attaching events in html like this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are putting in the onclick handler, you should just put as the href:

```
<a href="newpage.php?p=1&q=3" onmouseover="previewBox;">Preview</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't have a clue why you want to disable your "href" from the `<a>`, but if you really want to navigate by using the `onclick`, remember to use full javscript to do so:

```
<a onmouseover="previewBox;" onclick="window.location.href = 'newpage.php?p=1&q=3'">Preview</a>
```

​
By setting the `window.location.href` you can navigate with the click ([Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/qEmk6/)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to a new page by clicking your anchor you just put the location in the href instead of the onclick.